# Can't Fetch Database to Array inside Object in PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql, arrays, json

i have an android project that need to get database from my online database. I have develop code for Android but now i am stuck on the PHP code in case to fetch my online database.

Well, i am using JSON to fetch the database, so i code on the Android side like this one :

```
JSONArray j = new JSONArray(total);
                    JSONObject Obj = j.getJSONObject(i); 
                item.setId(Obj.getString(JF_ID));
                item.setTitle(Obj.getString(JF_TITLE));


                item.setAddress(Obj.getString(JF_ADDRESS));

                item.setTelephoneNumber(Obj.optString(JF_TELEPHONE, NO_DATA_FOUND));

                item.setEmailAddress(Obj.optString(JF_EMAIL, NO_DATA_FOUND));
                item.setWebUrl(Obj.optString(JF_WEB, NO_DATA_FOUND));
                item.setFacebookUrl(Obj.optString(JF_FACEBOOK, NO_DATA_FOUND));

                item.setLatitude(Obj.optDouble(JF_LATITUDE, NULL_LOCATION));
                item.setLongitude(Obj.optDouble(JF_LONGITUDE, NULL_LOCATION));
                try {
                    item.setRating(Float.parseFloat(Obj.optString(JF_RATING, NO_DATA_FOUND)));
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    item.setRating(0.0f);
                }

                try {
                    item.setRatingCount(Integer.parseInt(Obj.optString(JF_RATING_COUNT, NO_DATA_FOUND)));
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    item.setRatingCount(0);
                }

                item.setTagLine(Obj.optString(JF_TAG_LINE, NO_DATA_FOUND));
                item.setDescription(Obj.optString(JF_DESCRIPTION, NO_DATA_FOUND));
                item.setVerification(Obj.optString(JF_VERIFICATION, NO_DATA_FOUND).equals("1") ? true : false);


                JSONArray imgArr = Obj.getJSONArray("thumbImage");
                String[] imageThumb = new String[imgArr.length()];
```

You can see there, my pattern is fetch Array first and fetch Object and the last fetch Array again.

In other words, i want my result look like this example :

```
["arrayA":{"id":"1", "year":"2016","thumbnail":["a.jpg","b.jpg","c.jpg"]}]
```

Here's the problem, i can't make the PHP code on server side returning the pattern that i want. It's always retruning the Array > Object and just it, there's no Array again after the Object.

Here's the code for PHP that i write so far :

```
$qu=mysqli_query($con,"select * from car_rental where rental_id='1'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qu)) {
    $res [] =array($row, 
        $thumbImage[] =
        array(  "t1"=>$row['thumbImage1'],
                "t2"=>$row['thumbImage2'],
                "t3"=>$row['thumbImage3']
            ) ); 



}
$json["thumb"] = $res;

echo json_encode($json);
```

Please master help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention you want output like

```
["arrayA":{"id":"1", "year":"2016","thumbnail":["a.jpg","b.jpg","c.jpg"]}]
```

Try this php code instead

```
$qu=mysqli_query($con,"select * from car_rental where rental_id='1'");

$res = array();
$singleRecordSet = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qu)) {

    $singleRecordSet = $row;
    $multiRecordSet = array('thumb'=>array(
                                "t1"=>$row['thumbImage1'],
                                "t2"=>$row['thumbImage2'],
                                "t3"=>$row['thumbImage3']
                        )); 
    $res = array_merge($singleRecordSet,$multiRecordSet);               
}

$json["arrayA"] = $res;

echo json_encode($json);
```